# Categorical mediator and total effect estimation

Tags: causality, multinomial-logit

Let's say you have a linear variable ($X$) that has a causal effect on a final linear variable ($Y$) via a mediator which in turn is a categorical variable ($Z$).

$$ X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y $$

All these variables are observed.

These can be modeled like:

$$ \textbf p = \text{softmax}(\textbf a  + \textbf b X)  $$
$$ Z \sim \text{Categorical}(\textbf p) $$

The interpretation of $\textbf b$ is the effect of $X$ on $Z$ being a certain category.

The second part of the model is simpler, just a linear regression on a categorical variable:

$$ y = c_{Z} $$
$$ Y \sim \mathcal N (y, \sigma) $$

where $\textbf c$ is a vector with as many components as the categories of $Z$.

By regressing, we can get estimates on $\textbf b$ and $\textbf c$.

What is the total effect of $X$ on $Y$? Can it be expressed as a function of $\textbf b$ and $\textbf c$?

Comment: Is the categorical variable ordered?

Comment: @dimitriy no, regular category. The first step is just a multinomial regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is
$$E[Y \vert Z]=\Pr(Z=1 \vert X)\cdot \beta_1 + \cdots + \Pr(Z=k\vert X)\cdot \beta_k.$$
You want to know how that changes with $X$, so you can take the derivative:
$$\frac{\partial E[Y \vert Z]}{\partial X}=\frac{\Pr(Z=1 \vert X)}{\partial X}\cdot \beta_1 + \cdots + \frac{\Pr(Z=k\vert X)}{\partial X}\cdot \beta_k.$$

These derivatives are the marginal effects from the multinomial model.

You can calculate the overall effect by averaging this expression in your estimation sample.

Comment: Good news: the probability P(Z=z|X) is given in a closed form - with the softmax function. Bad news: The derivative is dependent on X :D

Comment: You can just use the observed value of X when evaluating the derivative for each observation and average. You can also plot this as a function of X.

Comment: Yes, i calculated credible intervals for the estimate for several (relevant, extreme and average) values of X, and made a forest plot.